# How to fetch all words after first line break?

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a string as follows:

```
User.
This is first line after line break.
This is second line after line break.
//Blank Line
This is fourth line.
```

How can I fetch all words which appear after the very first line break.
So in above case I want to retrieve :

```
This is first line after line break.
This is second line after line break.
//Blank Line
This is fourth line.
```

i.e anything which occurs after the next line of 'User'.

So basically the string will contain the following :

```
User\r\n\r\nThis is first line after line break. //and so on
```

I'm currently doing the following :

```
            // consider demoString is the string variable which holds the entire string mentioned above

commentStringToSearch = "User";
commentStringIndex = demoString.IndexOf(commentStringToSearch, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);                

if (commentStringIndex != -1)
{
             commentValue = demoString.Substring(commentStringIndex + commentStringToSearch.Length);          
}
```

But the problem with this code is that it'll fetch anything after the word 'User' including the blank space in first line.

My expected output is to get words as they are from the second line to the whichever is the last line.

As per above example my expected output is to get the following :

```
This is first line after line break.
This is second line after line break.
//Blank Line
This is fourth line.
```

(Ignore everything from first line and accept anything from second line onwards)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Split on Environment.NewLine.  Now you have all lines.  Proceed as necessary.

Comment: After you get the index of "User" just find the index of the first newline after that index.

Comment: @stuartd You should put that as an answer.

Comment: Do you just want everything after the first line, or everything after the first line that contains "User"?  It's really not clear if "User" being on the first line matters or not.  Also it's not clear if there's just one new line after "User" or two that you want to skip.

Comment: I have already mentioned in the very last line "(Ignore everything from first line and accept anything from second line onwards)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple way of doing this:

```
var newText = text.Substring(text.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine) + Environment.NewLine.Length);
```

Comment: I'd just like to add for OP: Of course you have to check your input beforehand: Not null, Not Empty, contains at least one linebreak ...

Answer (score 0):

**@stuartd's** answer solved my problem with a little modification as follows :

```
var newText = text.Substring(text.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine) + Environment.NewLine.Length +2);
```

The reason for adding 2 is because with @stuartd's solution the string variable will contain the following value :

```
\r\nThis is first line after line break. //and so on
```

As there's an unwanted **\r\n which is being carried over from the original string** it's necessary to add 2 to make the substring to skip them or else there would be an unnecessary blank being added in the beginning of the sting value.

And as **@Fildor** correctly pointed out it's necessary to validate the string before-hand for nulls etc.